# What is with this Error? It seems to have no reason for appearing

Tags: c++

```
7   IntelliSense: no suitable user-defined conversion from "Difficulty" to "Difficulty" exists  e:\ICS3U CT\CT\game.h   29  10  CT
```

That is the error. The affected portions of the file are listed below.

```
 typedef struct Difficulty{
char* name;
char* description;
bool cumulatesHungerLoss;
int rngMod;
Difficulty(char* n, char* desc, bool cumulate, int rng){
name = n;
description = desc;
cumulatesHungerLoss = cumulate;
rngMod = rng;
}

};
Difficulty& easy = Difficulty("EASY","Normal RNG and Hunger Loss",false,0);
Difficulty& hard = Difficulty("HARD","Harder RNG and cumulative Hunger Loss",true,5);
Difficulty& insane = Difficulty("INSANE","Very Hard RNG and Cumulative Hunger Loss",true,15);
Difficulty getById(int id){
    switch(id){
    case 0:
        return easy;
    break;
    case 1:
        return hard;
    break;
    case 2:
        return insane;
    break;
    }
    return *NULL;
}
```

The code is in C, I only defined a single struct type, called Difficulty. The error is on return easy; return hard; and return insane;.

This occur's a lot whenever I try to assign a value of a user defined type, to another value of that type. It is messing up my game, since I need to assign values of my user types, to arrays and return values from functions. This only affects some of my types. I can guarantee the uniqueness of every single Type I defined.

[edit]I was intending to write the code in C. The program I am writing is a C program, I am sorry if it seems to be in C++, and it might be interpreted in C++, though the intention was to write it in C.

Comment: The constructor and references indicate this is C++. If this isn't, then it won't work.

Comment: You defined (at least) two `Difficulty` types. There's at least one other definition of `Difficulty` somewhere you haven't shown us. Also, get rid of that `typedef`.

Comment: `return *NULL;`, NULL is just a macro for 0, you need to rethink how the function will respond to an invalid id.

Comment: user2357112: There is only one Difficulty Type, defined only in the file game.h. typedef is required since it is C code. InternetAussie, the intention is that the code is in C. It might be interperting it as C++ code. References are indeed in C, at least in the version I am using (Visual Studio 2012). George: I don't really know how to respond, to invalids except returning NULL. My background is in Java, and I only learned basic C, in my Grade 11 Computer Science Course, starting in September. I could probably return a default in any other case.

Answer (score 1):

It's C++, not C. I edited your question to fix that.

```
Difficulty& easy = Difficulty("EASY","Normal RNG and Hunger Loss",false,0);
Difficulty& hard = Difficulty("HARD","Harder RNG and cumulative Hunger Loss",true,5);
Difficulty& insane = Difficulty("INSANE","Very Hard RNG and Cumulative Hunger Loss",true,15);
```

The problem is you're attempting to bind temporary objects to non-const references. You don't need references, just define some named objects directly:

```
const Difficulty easy("EASY","Normal RNG and Hunger Loss",false,0);
const Difficulty hard("HARD","Harder RNG and cumulative Hunger Loss",true,5);
const Difficulty insane("INSANE","Very Hard RNG and Cumulative Hunger Loss",true,15);
```

That's not the only problem, but it's the one you asked about.

Comment: Still Gives me the error message, and the same one. It might be a problem with the Dev Enviroment: I am currently using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.